# Kafka roundtrip 2+ seconds

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

We observe high RTT Kafka latency for all messages.

This is our actual configuration:

- we have 3 Kafka brokers + 3 Zookeeper running in a Kubernetes cluster on EC2 servers
- we are using the [confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0-3 Kafka docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka/tags/)
- zookeeper + kafka configurations are pretty standard (except for `compression.type=gzip`)
- our NodeJS microservices are exchanging messages through Kafka

We observe high RTT Kafka latency for some messages: example scenario is `service1` holds both a Kafka producer and consumer. It produces `message1` to Kafka, then it takes on average ~3 seconds to the consumer - within the same service - to get `message1`.

We have run tests to exclude:

- network latency
- latency related to the message size
- latency provided by libraries that we use (two layers "from us", then [`node-rdkafka`](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka), then [`librdkafka`](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka)).

We've also tried what's suggested [here](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/issues/259) and [here](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/How-to-decrease-message-latency), but didn't solve the issue.

The latencies seem to be roughly multiples of 1s, so we suspect we're missing some tuning configuration on the kafka side.

My questions are:
- anyone with similar configuration has observed and/or resolved the same issue? How?
- how can we investigate further to understand who causes this high latency?

Comment: What EC2 instance types are you running the clients on? The clients are multi-threaded and don't perform that well on instances with a small number of cores

Comment: Both clients and brokers are on m4.large instances, but these instances are shared via a Kubernetes setup. We have not put any additional limits on CPU usage though, so if needed they should be able to use all CPU resources.

In terms of throughput though we're looking at low tens of messages per second right now, as this is an early stage setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity: I think we actually found the underlying problem.

We were reconnecting to the kafka broker for every sent message due to a bug in our client library, and that connecting is expensive.

We are still monitoring after having fixed that bug to see that this is indeed the cause.